# numpy ndarray from read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I generate a dataframe in my Python program. One column is a numpy ndarray with 10 elements
I then write it to excel, and use the dataframe further

To avoid regenerating the dataframe everytime I open Jupyter, I have the option to read directly the Excel file with read_excel function. This way I have my dataframe.
But it seems the nd array is not read such as: when I want to access an element, the return value is None.

Do you know how I can do?
Thanks for help

**Edit:**

My read_Excel code, and its ouput

```
s = path_territory_output+'\COM_DETAIL.xlsx'
COM_DETAIL = p.read_excel(s)
print(COM_DETAIL['COM_CLOSEST'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBBWN.png)

If I try to access first element of first row:

```
print(np.array(COM_DETAIL['COM_CLOSEST'])[0][0])
```

It outputs: "["

Comment: Can you give some more information? What have you tried so far? Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @DonPre I edited my post with some more information.

Comment: If you `print(np.array(COM_DETAIL['COM_CLOSEST'])[0])` what do you get as output?

Comment: Have you looked at the excel file?  Or tried to use it in any other way?  I don't think that's a good format for saving this dataframe.  `csv` wiil have similar problems.

Comment: In the new dataframe, the column values are strings.  csv/excel are 2d formats - rows and columns.  They can't save the extra dimension of your array values.  So they just save/read a string representation of the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a column from a dataframe, it will return a `pandas.Series` object. If you want it as an `ndarray`, you can do one of these:

- typecast to numpy array as: `np.array(df['col'])`
- call `to_numpy()` method on pandas series as: `df['col'].to_numpy()`

Comment: Hi, I edited my post, it still doesn't work for my with numpy.array :/

Comment: Can you check the type of the elements of the series? `type(COM_DETAIL['COM_CLOSEST'][0])`. It is supposed to be array-like to get the values, but it looks like the whole ndarray is is interpreted as a string

Comment: As @hpaulj mentioned, it is better to avoid this way of handling the data. But if you must do it this way, splitting the string by spaces and then calling each element should work.